# Formatting cells with the Google Sheets API (v4)

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using the Google Sheets API (v4) to create/update spreadsheets programmatically and have run into the following issue:

As per the documentation (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#CellFormat), I'm setting the number format to `CURRENCY`; this will correctly display the number as a numeric value with a ¥ sign at the front (Japanese locale). However, it does not seem to actually select the "Currency" option on the formats dropdown, and more importantly, does NOT reflect the specified format when downloading the spreadsheet (e.g. as an .xlsx file).

[image]

This is different from selecting the 'Currency' option manually (via the UI), in which case values are correctly displayed once downloaded.

[image]

Here's the relevant section of code:

```js
import { google, sheets_v4 } from 'googleapis';

const sheetsApi = google.sheets({
  version: 'v4',
  auth: await this.getAuthClient(),
});

await sheetsApi.spreadsheets
  .batchUpdate({
    spreadsheetId: resource,
    requestBody: {
      requests: [
        {
          updateSpreadsheetProperties: {
            fields: 'locale',
            properties: {
              locale: 'ja',
            },
          },
        },

        ...,
        
        {
          repeatCell: {
            fields: 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat',
            cell: {
              userEnteredFormat: {
                numberFormat: { type: 'CURRENCY' },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I've also tried settings the pattern (tried few different ones), but haven't been able to actually set the cell format, despite the value being displayed as such.

Probably a simple mistake, but I've been stuck on this for a while.. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case, I thought that the property of `pattern` might be required to be set. So in this case, how about modifying your request of `repeatCell` as follows?

#### Modified request:

```
{
  "repeatCell": {
    "range": {,,,}, // Please set range.
    "cell": {
      "userEnteredFormat": {
        "numberFormat": {
          "type": "CURRENCY",
          "pattern": "[$¥-411]#,##0.00"  // <--- Added
        }
      }
    },
    "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"  // or "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, when above modified request is used for the batchUpdate method, I could confirm that "Currency" was checked.

#### References:

- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)- [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#NumberFormat)

Comment: You're a lifesaver, Tanaike! Had actually tried several patterns myself (including the one written on their documentation), but failed to get it working; I guess it helps to know about patterns in the first place haha. Thanks again!

Comment: @delafuente-ricardo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike could you explain the reasoning behind `[$¥-411]` part of the pattern

Comment: @anushka About `@Tanaike could you explain the reasoning behind [$¥-411] part of the pattern`, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: @Tanaike nihongo de iidesuka? `[$¥-411]`の部分の理由が分からなくてどうして必要かを考えています

Comment: @anushka Thank you for replying. Although I cannot understand `どうして必要` of `[$¥-411]の部分の理由が分からなくてどうして必要かを考えています`, when OP's number format is manually reflected in a cell and the number format is retrieved from that cell, such value is retrieved. If this was not your expected explanation, I apologize again.